# Can I launch a jetty server for my gwt from my main method?

Tags: java, gwt, jetty

I have two applications.

One is a background application, which regularly checking some data in my database.

The other is a GWT application, which provide a simple UI to client to access a simple table.

My question is **can I combine these two applications into one?**

I am currently using `gwt devmode` to launch my GWT application. It is running fine.

But really, what I want are the followings:

1. I don't want any heavy TomCat or standalone web server.
2. I wish the two applications to be combined into one.
3. Either in my background application's `main()` method, I can launch `gwt-dev-mode` or `jetty server`
4. or I can easily deploy `jetty` server or just package the whole gwt application and run it with `gwt-dev-mode`, of course, launching my background application inside the jetty or gwt-dev-mode

can I do those?

Answer (score 0):

We are using the solution 4.
Our GWT app inherits from the project with the back-end logic. When launching dev mode the back-end logic runs as usual.

Do you have to call a main() whenever you want to start the background application ? We are using Spring and the beans managing the background processes are created automatically on start-up.

Your local server could also just call that process on start-up.